# in ruby's strftime, why is it that %P is "am/pm" and %p is "AM/PM"

Tags: ruby, datetime, strftime

isn't that more confusing? Shouldn't it be the other way around so it's easier to remember?

Comment: im not planning to change it, i just asked why :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looking at this cheat sheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/strftime/

It seems that Ruby 1.8 didn't have the %P option before, so I think that when the  community chose to add that "feature" in, they chose to use %p for backwards compatibility and added the %P option for users who wanted the lowercase version.

Still, it wouldn't have hurt if they were interchanged to avoid confusion.

Comment: Interchanging will create confusion. Usually, lower case is for default use, upper case is for marked use. Since AM/PM are acronyms, capitalizing them are the correct usage, and that's the default.